# Dynamically sum each row and column by arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

This shouldn't be too hard, but I can't figure it out. Please have a look at [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mdM7KDdpl_I8CEP5FK834t3Vt57vuLISIyOLH231fLw/edit?usp=sharing). Sample:

```
| Jan '17   | Feb '17      | Mar '17      | Apr '17   |           |
|-----------|--------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|
|           | SUM COLUMN B | SUM COLUMN C | [...]     |           |
| SUM ROW 3 | 0.00         | 0.00         | 13,954.00 | 13,954.00 |
| SUM ROW 4 | 0.00         | 0.00         | 0.00      | 0.00      |
| [...]     | 0.00         | 0.00         | 0.00      | 0.00      |
```

I need to sum all each column in **Row 2** and each row in **Column A**. However, since the columns and rows in this document are added dynamically, I want to accomplish this by using an arrayformula or similar.

I've tried using

```
=MMULT(B3:AK,TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(B3:AK)^0)))
```

for summing rows in **column A**, this will yield incorrect results when a new column is added. Extending the range to `B3:AAA` causes errors in MMULT.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) for this.

Column sum in B2 would be `=columnSum(B3:1000000)` and row sum in A3 would be `=rowSum(B3:1000000)`. The functions perform the summation required, treating blank cells as zeros (something that `mmult` has a problem with).

```
function columnSum(values) {
  return [values.reduce(function(sums, row) {
    return sums.map(function(s, i) {
      return (s || 0) + (row[i] || 0);
    });
  })];
}

function rowSum(values) {
  return values.map(function(row) { 
    return row.reduce(function(s, x) {
      return (s || 0) + (x || 0);
    });
  });
}
```